# How to structure SQL data model to maintain data integrity

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, erd, application-design

### Background

I'm building a Private Chef booking service where you can book a Chef to cook you a custom Menu.  I'm having trouble creating a SQL db schema that accurately represents the domain while maintaining data integrity.

#### Requirements

- Customers create a `Booking` by selecting a `Chef` and a `Menu` and choose the `MenuItems` they want for each `MenuCourse`
- A `Chef` defines a set of `MenuItem` that a customer can choose from to create their `Booking`
- A `Menu` is a collection of `MenuCourses`. (ex. A `Menu` named "Tasting Menu" is a 6 course meal, where each `MenuCourse` costs between $10-20).
- A `Chef` should be able to associate their `MenuItems` with multiple `Menus` and `MenuCourses`.
- A customer `Booking` should contain the `Chef` the customer selected along with the `Menu` (and the `MenuItems`) that will be served. `Booking` price is determined by the `Menu` and `MenuCourse` selections (an appetizer costs less than an entree)

## Problem

In my current data model, I have the following issues that I'm not sure how to fix:

- it's possible to create a `Booking` with `Chef` "A", but then have a `BookingMenuItem` that references a `MenuItem` with `Chef` "B" (all the `BookingMenuItem` for a `Booking` should belong to the same `Chef`)
- a `Booking` references a particular `Menu` (which I need for pricing, pricing is based on `Menu` and `MenuCourse`) however a `BookingMenuItem` for that `Booking` could reference a completely different `Menu` or `MenuCourse`

Is it possible to re-design my db schema to fix the integrity problems I'm having? Or do I just have to implement these checks at the application level. Thanks!

[image: ERD]

Comment: duplicate of SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347956/how-to-structure-sql-data-model-to-maintain-data-integrity/61406568#61406568